# Exposed wiring outside

Tags: electrical

I tore down an old shed that have electricity going to it. Now the shed is gone but I have an exposed wire outside. I want to install a small street light there next spring but what should I do with the electricle wiring till then? The wires still have power going to them because the shed didn't have its own breaker.

Comment: Is it a direct burial cable, or conduit?

Answer (score 6):

1. Pound a 2' - 3' pressure treated 2x4 into the ground, so that about 12" to 18" is above ground (cutting an angle in the end going into the ground, will help it go in better).
2. Mount a weatherproof 1-gang electrical box on the 2x4.
3. Pull the wiring into the box, using the appropriate clamp/bushing.
4. Secure the wiring to the 2x4 below the box, using an appropriate means.
5. Cap the wires off using weatherproof twist-on wire connectors.
6. Cover the box with a weatherproof blank cover.

[image: Weatherproof box]
[image: Weatherproof blank cover]
[image: Weatherproof twist-on wire connectors]

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to find out where the wire exits the house.  Then with the power off, cut the wire, install a steel box, and cap the wires off with wire nuts inside the steel box.  When you re-install, you can splice inside the box, as long as it is accessible.